# Exporting excel worksheet into ms access table

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access, export

How can I import an excel worksheet into an MS Access table every time new data is added to the worksheet? Meaning every time I update my excel worksheet it would automatically update the ms access table?

I searched the internet and it seems there are several ways that it can be done, however I can't find a method that does exactly what I want. What I have so far isn't working nor does it do what I want it to do in the end. However, it is a start.

As I said I want vba to continuously update my access table through the excel worksheet. Right now the code isn't working. It keeps saying "path not found."

I tried debugging, but I haven't been able to figure out what was wrong with the path.  This is what I have so far. Any suggestions on how to fix my code and or any suggestions for an easier way?

```
      Sub ExportToAccess()
Dim oSelect As Range, i As Long, j As Integer, sPath As String
Sheet1.Activate
Set oSelect = Application.InputBox("Range", , Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address, , , , , 8)

Dim oDAO As DAO.DBEngine, oDB As DAO.Database, oRS As DAO.Recordset
ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path
sPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Access * test.accdb\")
If sPath = "False" Then Exit Sub

Set oDAO = New DAO.DBEngine
Set oDB = oDAO.OpenDatabase(sPath)
Set oRS = oDB.OpenRecordset("ImportedData")
For i = 2 To oSelect.Rows.Count
    oRS.AddNew
    For j = 1 To oSelect.Columns.Count
        oRS.Fields(j) = oSelect.Cells(i, j)
    Next j
        oRS.Update
Next i
oDB.Close

If MsgBox("Open the table?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    Dim oApp As Access.Application
    Set oApp = New Access.Application
    oApp.Visible = True
    oApp.OpenCurrentDatabase sPath
    oApp.DoCmd.OpenTable "ImportedData", acViewNormal, acReadOnly
    oApp.DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast
    DoEvents


 End If
 End Sub
```

Problem solved:
Though the method I used to solve my problem worked for me it might not be what most people would be expecting when seeing this post, however I still think it could be useful to some. Even though the solution I came up with is very simple. Instead of directly writing some code to transfer the data in my worksheet to an access table I simply had my vba code copy and paste the data that was entered into worksheet 1 then paste it into worksheet 2, then I linked worksheet 2 to an access table using the external data import function in access.

Comment: *so far isn't working nor does it do what I want it to do in the end* - why isn't working? What is it not doing that you want it to do? Or vice-versa?

Comment: The title says _import_ while your code tries to _export_. So what do you really want to do?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman  title was typo, meant export, I need to have excel vba to continuously take the information from excel and paste it into a table in access, so every time someone updates the excel worksheet the new information is also updated in  the access table. What isn't working is the file path, It keeps saying "path not found"

Comment: debug the code and check the value of `sPath` and make sure it's a valid path (which technically, it should be since you are using a filepicker dialog.

Comment: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) -- if that doesn't help: **which line** causes the error?

Comment: @Andre this is the line of code that errors `ChDir ActiveWorkbook.Path`